# Devexpress BatchEdit cell style - Simulate input

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress and I have an ASPxGridView that can be modified by BatchEdit.

This grid only have some cells that can be edited, and even on the same column some cells can be modified and others not (it depends on some conditions and I control that by JS with OnBatchStartEdit)

I want that the user could see quickly which cells are ready for edit and which ones not. I thought about simulating an style like if it were an input with CSS with outline and outline-offset, but outline-offset does not work on IE and without it, it is really ugly.

Another option I thought was with a border + radius, but with radius the background color of the cells outside the radius stays in white, and I don't want that because all the row must have the same color.

Do you have any solution to the issues of the options above or a new way to do what I want?